# Create Password Validator

Tags: ruby

I’m new to ruby, so I want to challenge myself to make a Password Validator, to make the password is valid or not, it needs to match the following conditions

- Have at least 7 characters
- Have minimum 2 of the following special character('!', '@', '#', '$',
  '%', '&', '*')
- Have at least 2 number

So I wrote this:

```
numberOfSymbol=0
numberOfNumbers=0
totalNumber=0
numberArray=(0..9).to_a
inputPassword=gets.chomp
symbol=['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*']
neededHash={}
neededHash.default=0
randomGeneratedVar=[]
pppppp=0
symbol.each do |sym|
    if inputPassword.include?(sym)
        numberOfSymbol+=1
    end
end
numberArray.each do |x|
    inputPassword.each_char do |y|
        if x.to_s == y
            neededHash[y] += 1
            randomGeneratedVar = neededHash.values
        end
    end
end
randomGeneratedVar.each {|z| pppppp+=z}
if numberOfSymbol >= 2 && inputPassword.length >= 7 && pppppp >=2
      puts "Strong"
else
      puts "Weak"
end
```

After I ran this through the tester it satisfied 16 cases out of 18 cases, I wonder if you guys can help me to perfect this code.

Comment: _“it satisfied 16 cases out of 18 cases”_ – what were the failing ones?

Comment: I don’t really know because it only shows the input of first two cases,the others are hidden

Comment: Does the password have to include 2 _different_ symbols or just 2 symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need these amount of variables to create validator.

I think this looks more simple and easy to understand:

```rb
def password_validator(password)
  symbols = %w(! @ # $ % & *)
  counter = 0
  symbols.each do |element|
    if password.include?(element)
      counter += 1
    end
  end
  if password.length >= 7 && password.tr("^0-9 ", "").length >= 2 && counter >= 2
    "password is valid"
  else
    "password not valid"
  end
end
```

1. Symbols is an array of symbols
2. Walk on each symbol and initializing include?
3. Just condition if password length >= 7 AND password numbers length >= 2 AND counter of symbols is >= 2

Comment: Thank you for helping me,I’m really grateful.Because I have just learned ruby for a week so I can’t really use the potential ability of what I have learned,that is why the code looks like a mess,but I’m really appreciate for the help

Comment: Just google and read ruby documentation (i use this: https://apidock.com/ruby) ! For example: "Google -> How to delete all digits from string"

Answer (score 0):

The ruby way and also simple way

```
def password_complexity
    if password.present? && password =~ /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[@$!%*?&]{2})[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{7,}$)/
     puts "Strong Password"
    else
     put "Complexity requirement not met. Please use: 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 2 digit and 2 special character, 7 characters"
    end 
 end
```

If you want you can change regular expression, please find some of the examples
Minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$"
```

Minimum eight characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$"
```

Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one number:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$"
```

Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$"
```

Minimum eight and maximum 10 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,10}$"
```

The Rails way

```
PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
      (?=.{7,})          # Must contain 8 or more characters
      (?=.*\d)           # Must contain a digit
      (?=.*[a-z])        # Must contain a lower case character
      (?=.*[A-Z])        # Must contain an upper case character
      (?=.*[[:^alnum:]]) # Must contain a symbol
    /x

validates :password, 
  presence: true, 
  length: { in: 15 }, 
  format: { with: PASSWORD_FORMAT }, 
  confirmation: true
```

I have given just example you can modify as per your requirement, Please read this for more information

https://medium.com/@Timothy_Fell/how-to-set-password-requirements-in-rails-d9081926923b

Comment: Thank you for helping me,your code looks so simple,I haven’t think about using regex so your code helps me so much.Thank you

Comment: If `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[@$!%*?&]{2})[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{7,}$)/` qualifies as "simple", I don't want to see the complex one ;-)

Comment: "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)"
"[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)"